# DRF how to return multiple datas inside the same serializer

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework, nested, response

I will try to make my problem as simple as possible:

I have this serializer:

```
class DatesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
    ... bunch of stuff and Others serializers
```

and on my view.py I have this piece of code:

```
dates = ["2021-05-02", "2021-06-28", "2021-07-02"]
...
for date in dates:
    faults = DatesSerializer({
         "date":date,
         ...
    })
return Response({"faults":faults.data, status=200})
```

I receive a response like these:

```
{
 "faults":{
            "date":"2021-07-02"
            ....
          }
}
```

what I wanted was a response like this one

```
{
 "faults":{
            "date":"2021-07-02"
            ....
          },
          {
            "date":"2021-06-28"
            ....
          },              {
            "date":"2021-05-02"
            ....
          }
}
```

I understand that on my loop I'm overwriting my serializer and that's why I just have the last entry, but I have tried to overcome this by adding on a dict and got nowhere since the key will always be the same, and I'm stuck on how to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not a valid object. You want a list, and this easily can be accomplished in a loop by appending serializer data on each iteration.

```
res = []

for date in dates:
    serializer = DatesSerializer({
         "date":date,
         ...
    })
    res.append(serializer.data)
return Response({ "faults": res }, status=200)
```